# EF 4.3 DB first model not importing associations

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-4.3

We moved our DB from an instance of SQL 2005 to a new SQL 2008r2 server. We changed the connection strings in our app to point to new database, even modified the ProviderManifestToken from 2005 to 2008. Everything was working fine until we tried to add entities from our database to our existing edmx model. I'm using the 'update model from database' wizard to add tables to the edmx diagram. The tables will appear in the diagram but only some have their associations and/or foreign keys imported. If I switch the connection string to point back to the old 2005 sql instance everything imports correctly and associations are present. I'm happy to provide additional details if necessary. I can't find a pattern to this at all. What gives?

Update: I created a new project, added an edmx, pointed it to the 2008r2 db instance, selected tables that I know have associations but the designer failed to pick up the associations. Is there something I need to install on the SQL server to get EF to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working for now. Deleting the connection string from the web.config and then using 'Update Model from Database' and going through the 'Add new connection' dialog to point to the database on the new server seemed to make it behave. If this stops working I'll post back.

Update: Turns out I had two problems. The second was that one of the tables in our DB had two nearly identical redundant indexes on the same column; a clustered PK index and a unique, non-clustered index. So any time I created a foreign key pointing to this table the database chose the unique non-clustered index to enforce the constraint (why? I don't know). But Entity Framework didn't like it and would not create or even recognize the foreign key association. I had to delete the extra non-clustered index and re-create all the foreign keys so they would point to the clustered index. Once that was done I updated my model from the database and all associations were present.

Here's the SQL query I used to check which indexes my foreign keys were using:
    `SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C 
    ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME`
The `UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME` column for the FK in question should point to a clustered PK for it to work.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for providing all this detail in the update. DB did the same to me on SQLServer 2012, despite the indices being of completely different data types (int vs nvarchar)!

Answer (score 0):

How did you move the database to the 2008 Server?  Sounds like some or all of the relationships/constraints were not migrated.  That would explain why the associations are not showing up when you point to the 2008 database.

Comment: I created a new DB on the 2008 instance and restored a backup against it from the 2005 instance.

Comment: The relationships/constraints definitely preset on the 2008 instance.